# Angular - UI not updated when submitting form

Tags: angular, solr, httprequest, angular2-observables

I am building an enterprise application in Angular. I cannot seem to find anyone who has posted a similar enough situation that I can adapt to help resolve the problem I'm experiencing.

**App Functionality:** 
This is a fundamental angular application which makes a httpGet call to the Solr back-end via a submission form and displays the results via a component view.

**Problem:** 
The initial httpGet call is fired from the root component (fbsearch index) with seed data. This works as the results render in the results component as designed. The NETWORK section of the browser developer tools captures the request params and the 200 is returned.

The issue is seen when the query parameters are passed by the form. I am able to track the parameters through the process via console.log statements. I notice that when the function (getHttpResponseDocs) should be triggered it is not. The NETWORK section shows no indication that the request was made. This seems to suggest that the subscribe() function is not working as designed.

ONE other anomaly that I'm noticing (of which I do not understand the significance) - is when clicking the Solr queryString as captured in the console from the initial httpGet - the url redirects to the NETWORK tab. When the Solr queryString has been built from the form parameters, clicking on it in console returns the response from Solr.

I don't know how this fits into the issue - but thought I'd mention it. I am fairly new to Angular so I'm not well-versed in troubleshooting these types of applications. But from what I know - the issue is pointing to a problem with the subscription. I just don't know how to resolve this.

The complete code can be found here: https://github.com/r2c0der/mvc_fbsearch.

**NOTE:** 
When testing this, inputs must start with a capital letter (Solr thing). This is addressed in the production code. Also, only the last name is required.

**Input Form Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";
import {MVCFBSearchQueryParamsService} from "../../services/fbsearch-query-params.service";
import {FBSearchQueryParamsModel} from "../../services/model/fbsearch-query-params.model";
import {MVCFBSearchSolrService} from "../../services/fbsearch-solr.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'mvc-fbsearch-query-form',
  templateUrl: './fbsearch-query-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fbsearch-query-form.component.css']
})
export class MVWFBSearchQueryFormComponent implements OnInit {

  //populating the dropdown menus in the UI
  states = [];
  years = [];
  fbsearchQueryForm:FormGroup;
  constructor(
    private _queryParamService: MVCFBSearchQueryParamsService,
    private _solrService: MVCFBSearchSolrService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    //populating the dropdown menus in the UI
    this.states = statesAry;
    this.years = yearAry;
    this.buildForm();
  }
//buildform() - assembles the inputs into form group



  onSubmit(formValues: FBSearchQueryParamsModel){

    //Informs FBSeachIndex to uncollapse filters on form submission
    this._queryParamService.formSubmitted.next(true);

    let queryParams: FBSearchQueryParamsModel = {
      fbLastName: formValues.fbLastName,
      fbFirstName: formValues.fbFirstName,
      fbState: formValues.fbState,
      fbYear: formValues.fbYear

    }
       this._solrService.buildQueryString(queryParams);
  }


}


const statesAry = [
  {abbrev: '', option: ''},
  {abbrev:  'al', option: 'Alabama'},
  {abbrev:  'ar', option: 'Arkansas'},
  {abbrev:  'ca', option: 'California'},
  {abbrev:  'co', option: 'Colorado'},
  {abbrev:  'ct', option: 'Connecticut'}

];
const yearAry = [
  {abbrev: '', option: ''},
  {option: '186*'},
  {option: '1863'},
  {option: '1864'},
  {option: '1865'}
];
```

**Input Form Component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <fieldset>
        <label for="query_form" class="nmaahc_fbsearch_form-label"> Search the Records </label>
        <!-- SEARCH FORM -->
        <form  novalidate [formGroup]="fbsearchQueryForm"  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(fbsearchQueryForm.value)" class="form-horizontal" autocomplete="off" name="nmaahc_fb_query-form" id="query_form" >

          <div class="form-group"   >
            <input formControlName="fbLastName" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg " name="fbLastName" id="fbLastName"  placeholder="Last Name" required  />
          </div>  <!-- lastName -->
          <br />
          <div class="form-group"   >
            <input formControlName="fbFirstName" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="fbFirstName" id="fbFirstName"  placeholder="First Name"  />
          </div>  <!-- firstName -->
          <br />
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fbState" class="control-label nmaahc_fbsearch_form-label ">State </label>
            <select formControlName="fbState" id="fbState" class="nmaahc_fbsearch_form-options form-control" name="fbState" id="fbState">
              <option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state.option">{{state.option}}</option>
            </select>
          </div><!-- state -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fbYear" class="control-label nmaahc_fbsearch_form-label float-label-control">Year </label>
            <select formControlName="fbYear" id="fbYear" class="nmaahc_fbsearch_form-options form-control" name="fbYear" id="fbYear">

              <option *ngFor="let year of years" [value]="year.option">{{year.option}}</option>
            </select>
          </div><!-- year -->

          <div class="form-group"> <!-- Submit button !-->
            <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn nmaahc_fbsearch_form-btn"
            >Submit Query</button>
            <button type="reset" id="btnReset" class="btn nmaahc_fbsearch_form-btn" >Clear Query</button>
          </div> <!--  buttons -->
        </form><!-- END FORM -->
      </fieldset> <!-- fieldset -->
    </div><!-- COLUMN FIRST -->
  </div>
</div><!-- FBSEARCH_FORM -->
```

**SolrService**

```
import {Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FBSearchQueryParamsModel} from "./model/fbsearch-query-params.model";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {FBSearchHttpResponseModel} from "./model/fbsearch-response.model";

@Injectable()
export class MVCFBSearchSolrService implements OnInit {


queryUrl: string;
private solrBaseUrl = 'http://fbsearch.nmaahc.si.edu:8089/solr/aws_freedmens_fbs';
private solrQueryType = '/select?';


constructor(private _http: Http) { }
ngOnInit(): void {}

buildQueryString(queryParams: FBSearchQueryParamsModel){

console.log('SolrService - BuildQueryString')
let firstname = queryParams.fbFirstName;
console.log(firstname);

let lastname = queryParams.fbLastName;
console.log(lastname);

let year = queryParams.fbYear;
console.log(year);

let state = queryParams.fbState;
console.log(state);


let queryAppend = "fq=FB_FIRST_NAME:"+firstname+"*&indent=on&q=FB_LAST_NAME:"+lastname+"*&wt=json";
// console.log(queryAppend);

let queryString = this.solrBaseUrl+this.solrQueryType+queryAppend;
// console.log(queryString);

this.queryUrl = queryString;
// console.log(this.queryUrl);
}

getHttpResponseDocs():Observable<FBSearchHttpResponseModel[]>{

return this._http.get(this.queryUrl)
.map((response)=>response.json());
}

}
```

**Results List Component**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MVCFBSearchSolrService} from "../../services/fbsearch-solr.service";
import "rxjs/add/operator/do";

@Component() //has the expected metadata
export class MVCFBSearchResultsListComponent implements OnInit {

  results$:any[];

  constructor(private _solrService: MVCFBSearchSolrService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this._solrService.getHttpResponseDocs()
      .map((data)=>{
      this.results$ = data;
      })
      .subscribe((res)=>console.log(res));    
  }    
}
```

**Results List Component.html**

```
<div >
<h2>Results List Component</h2>
<p *ngIf="(numFound$ | async) as numFound; else noneFound ">
Your search returned {{ numFound }} record(s).
<br /> <em>Displaying {{ rows$ | async }} of {{ numFound  }} records.</em>  </p>
<div *ngFor="let response of (results$ | async )  ">

<div  class="well hoverwell nmaahc_fb_results-thumbnail">
<!--- RECORD HEADER -->
<h4 class="nmaahc_fb_pub-title"> {{response.FB_PUB_TITLE}}</h4>
<h3 class="nmaahc_fb_name">{{response.FB_FIRST_NAME}}&nbsp; {{response.FB_LAST_NAME}}</h3>
<div *ngIf="response?.FB_RECORD_TYPE"><span> {{response.FB_RECORD_TYPE}}</span></div>
<br />
<div *ngIf="response?.FB_RECORD_STATE"> <span>{{response.FB_RECORD_STATE}}</span></div>

</div>   
</div>

<ng-template #noneFound>
<p>No records were found to match your search.</p>
</ng-template>
</div>
```

**Models**

```
export interface FBSearchQueryParamsModel {

fbFirstName?: string;
fbLastName: string;
fbState?: string;
fbYear?: string;
fbPubNum?:string;

}

export interface FBSearchResponseModel {
response:[
{
numFound:number;
start:number;
docs:FBSearchResultsModel[]
}
];
}

export interface FBSearchResponseHeaderModel {
responseHeader:[{
status:number;
QTime: number;
params:string[];
}];
}
```

**Index Component**

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'mvc-fbsearch-index',
  template:`    
    <!--<fbsearch-header></fbsearch-header>-->
    <h2>Hola Moto!</h2>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
          <mvc-fbsearch-query-form></mvc-fbsearch-query-form>
          <!--<fbsearch-query-form></fbsearch-query-form>-->



        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <mvc-fbsearch-results-list></mvc-fbsearch-results-list>
          <!--<fbsearch-results-list ></fbsearch-results-list>-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
,
  styleUrls: ['./fbsearch-index.component.css']
})
export class MVCFBSearchIndexComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the minimal code to reproduce the issue? Way too much code I would say.. perhaps check [how to create a MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It is my first time posting to the forum so the guidance is helpful. AND your suggestion to reduce to MVC may help me find the answer. I will repost if i cannot.

Comment: UPDATE: Issue was solved - based on the suggestion, I refactored the code. There were a number of issues, the problematic portion was the Observable subscription. Cleaned up the SolrService httpGet:   this._http.get(<params>)
   .subscribe((res: Response)=>{
    const data = res.json();
  
      this.resultsSubject.next(data.response.docs);
          this.stateFacetSubject.next(data.facet_counts.facet_fields.FB_STATE);

    this.yearFacetSubject.next(data.facet_counts.facet_fields.FB_YEAR);
        
  });